# When does an after_create get fired in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am reading the docs and they this above the AR lifecycle hooks:

> Callbacks are hooks into the life cycle of an Active Record object
>   that allow you to trigger logic before or after an alteration of the
>   object state. This can be used to make sure that associated and
>   dependent objects are deleted when destroy is called (by overwriting
>   before_destroy) or to massage attributes before they're validated (by
>   overwriting before_validation). As an example of the callbacks
>   initiated, consider the Base#save call for a new record:
>
> (-) save
>
> (-) valid
>
> (1) before_validation
>
> (-) validate
>
> (2) after_validation
>
> (3) before_save
>
> (4) before_create
>
> (-) create
>
> (5) after_create
>
> (6) after_save
>
> (7) after_commit

So does this mean an after_create hook gets called after these calls:

.save
.create
.valid

Answer (score -1):

I found this: 
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

> after_save runs both on create and update, but always after the more specific callbacks after_create and after_update, no matter the order in which the macro calls were executed.

Comment: the question is about the specific callback "after_create" and not "after_save"